# subsetting with map function

Tags: r, purrr

Hi I want to calculate quantiles for numerical variables in data frame. Each variable should be filtered to not equal 0 before calculating quantiles. I would like to do it within map call but I don't know how to do this filtering

```
df<-data.frame(a=sample(0:5,100,replace = T),
               b=sample(0:5,100,replace = T))
df%>%map(~quantile(.,seq(0,0.9,0.1)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean like this?

```
filter_all(df, all_vars(. > 0)) %>% map(~quantile(.,seq(0,0.9,0.1)))

$a
 0% 10% 20% 30% 40% 50% 60% 70% 80% 90% 
  1   1   2   2   3   3   4   4   5   5 

$b
 0% 10% 20% 30% 40% 50% 60% 70% 80% 90% 
  1   1   2   3   3   3   4   4   4   5
```

This is also a possibility

```
map(df, ~ .[.>0] %>% quantile(seq(0,0.9,0.1)))
```

The first one filters the whole row if one element is <= 0, the other one only the single element.

Comment: not really because this filter rows where all values are above 0.  But the logic is take column A filter only rows where A!=0 and calculate quantiles without regards what is in other columns. And then the same for column B